# Want to Join Two table without Knowing other Table Name Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
$users = DB::table('table1')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();

$joinedtable = DB::table('table1')
->join('' . $users[0]->tablename . '', 'table1.id', '=', '' . $users[0]->tablename . '.id')
->get();
```

I want to join two table, 1st table name is given and 2nd  is comming from table1. I want to short this query and want to done using one query. Is it possible

Current O/P

```
[items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [country] => table2
                    [test1] => 23423
                    [test2] => 234234
                    [newdata1] => 1
                    [newdata2] => 1
                    [newdata3] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [country] => table3
                    [test1] => 123
                    [test2] => 123
                    [newdata1] => 2
                    [newdata2] => 2
                    [newdata3] => 2
                )

        )
```

Comment: you can try parameter grouping [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: in my case we do not have table name. In parameter grouping we will get all the data after query run than how we will get table name in beetween.

Comment: in that case pluck the table name and then join it

Comment: Can you tell in more details..

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution Option**

Use `pluck()` to get the table name and then join the tables.

```
$table2 = DB::table('table1')->where('id', '=', '1')->pluck('columnname');
```

Comment: i want only one query for both. This will run two saparate as i im using currently

Comment: i dont think u can do that without 2 calls.

Comment: hope will get otherwise having this one.